# Getting AWS Lambda RequestID, Request timestamp etc from FastAPI

Tags: amazon-web-services, fastapi

I have created a simple app that uses FastAPI with AWS API Gateway and AWS Lambda functions.

The following codes works well I am able to update user information in the database.

Additionally, i want to retrieve the metadata from AWS Lambda function such as the request timestamp, or request id etc for logging purpose.

I thought the `request` variable would have store it, but when I check it, it only has the user_id & user_type.

How can I get the AWS Lambda function metadata? I still want to retain the usage of FastAPI.

```
from main import update_user
from mangum import Mangum
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


class UpdateUser(BaseModel):
    user_id: str
    user_type: str


@app.get("/")
def home():
    return 'welcome'


@app.post("/update_user")
def predict(request: UpdateUser):
    print("this is request", request)
    user_id = request.user_id
    user_type = request.user_type

    response = update_user(user_id=user_id, user_type=user_type)

    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Was struggling with GPT-4 hallucination.

Solution is straight forward and can be found in mangum website

https://mangum.io/adapter/#creating-an-aws-lambda-handler